# Is there a way to make chrome autofill all available fields on a page, as opposed to requiring dropdown selection for each field?

Tags: google-chrome, automation, forms, auto-form-fill

If I have a field (e.g. mobile number) chrome will suggest the answer as I type, but is there any way for chrome to simply fill in the information without me having to manually trigger each field?

I'm submitting the same webform hundreds of times, and chrome knows what I want to type, I'd just like it to auto-autofill in that info.

Comment: It depends on how the form was created.  Each field needs an identifier in order to be auto-filled.  Some forms don't have an identifier for every field, sometimes on purpose (example: force you to re-enter a value for confirmation).

Comment: These forms have available autofill data, but want I want is to not have to click on the field and type something to prompt it to be filled.  Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: I'm not a Chrome user, but the auto-fill in a number of browsers will fill in everything it can when the page is loaded, and there are endless formfill plug-ins and software that don't wait for typing in a box to autofill.

Comment: @fixer1234 that's what I'm looking for

Comment: I rolled back your tag edit.  Explicitly requesting software recs is off-topic.  Have you looked at the available add-ins?

Comment: You can do this natively in Chrome or use an add-on like LastPass to do this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As posted in the comments, it seems Chrome won't do this without an extension.

[this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autofill/nlmmgnhgdeffjkdckmikfpnddkbbfkkk?hl=en) (confusingly just called "autofill") seems to do the job well.