# How to make Chrome autofill form on page load?

Tags: google-chrome, auto-form-fill

Is there any built-in way in Chrome (version 65) to autofill forms on page load? Specifically, without using a user-installed extension.

I'd further like it to autofill even if there's an `autofill="please-dont"` attribute on the input elements, although this detail is somewhat technical (so any way to get Chrome to autofill on page load would still be helpful).

I'm currently remotely troubleshooting an issue for admin users of a webapp, and the videos they send clearly indicate that form fields have been autofilled on page load. Being able to replicate this locally would be very useful. I don't expect any extensions to be installed, hence the request for a built-in way.

Comment: There is an extension on this link: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autofill/nlmmgnhgdeffjkdckmikfpnddkbbfkkk?hl=en But you seem sure that you dont want extensions

Comment: Yep, thanks for the link, but I've found those already (they could be useful for other people who find this question, though!). I'm troubleshooting for some non-technical users, and I wouldn't expect any extensions to be involved. But, come to think of it, I should probably check with them.

Comment: I've confirmed with the user I'm assisting that there aren't any autofill-related extensions installed.

Answer (score 0):

[This question on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/960197/is-there-a-way-to-make-chrome-autofill-all-available-fields-on-a-page-as-oppose?rq=1) says that Chrome simply does not auto-autofill all required fields on a webpage without an extension/add-on. This is probably because it has to ask your permission before doing such a thing, and it's a serious security problem.

Your best bet is to [install an extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autofill/nlmmgnhgdeffjkdckmikfpnddkbbfkkk?hl=en) or create a script inside your web app to fill all the fields automatically(From the user's cache, perhaps).

Comment: Any idea how this might be occurring, apparently without an extension, for some admin users? It seems to target email/password/twitter handle, although that might be a non-exhaustive list.